# Detecting onClick of a button present in another frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML page I have two frames- `top_frame` & `bottom_frame`. In `top_frame` there's a button `<input type='button' id='test' value='Test' name='test'>`

Now in `bottom_frame` I want to detect whether the button in `top_frame` is clicked or not.

Now normally without frames I could have done like this -

```
$("#test").click(function(){
   alert("You Clicked Me!!");
});
```

How can I do the same in frames ?

Comment: What kind of frames? Do you mean iframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second parameter of the jquery selector. It sets the context...

```
$("#test", window.parent.frames[0].document).click(function(){
   alert("You Clicked Me!!");
});
```